# Producer can not connect to broker through DNS

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python, apache-kafka-connect, pykafka

I have a physical server, where i have set the advertised.host.name to server ip, and do the port forwarding at the router. But the producer cannot connect to broker by using the dns.

ERROR:pykafka.connection:Failed to connect to 192.168.1.3:9092
WARNING:pykafka.producer:Broker 192.168.1.3:9092 disconnected. Retrying.

Comment: And your question is what? And what have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: peter, the question is pykafka producer not able to connect to the broker and send message through the DNS to my server. i have change the advertised.host.name in server.properties but not working.

Comment: @Yong, check that the port 9092 on 192.168.1.3 is open and there is the expected service there. Doesn't look like a DNS issue as you are using the IP address (DNS is the service translating a domain into an IP).

Comment: @Pixou port 9092 on 192.168.1.3 is open it's not working, and i have do the port forwarding at router for public ip to private ip also no working.

Comment: do you "telnet 192.168.1.3 9092"? was connect?